# How do I handle a MySQL query with multiple parameters whilst using Angular / Express

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I am designing a used cars website using AngularJS and NodeJS/Express. The database is MySQL (so not quite a MEAN stack).

I am very familiar with Angular but this is the first time I have used Express (in the past I have gone for JAX-RS).

I have no problem whilst only sending one or two paramaters e.g.

```
app.get('/api/images/:vehicleId', function (request, response) {
    images.getThumbnailImage(request, response, connection, request.params.vehicleId);
});
```

but I am unsure how to move forward with multiple parameters, some of which are optional.

The client is built using TypeScript. The form data is collected by way of a TypeScript object, but I am not sure what the best practice is for sending multiple parameters.

The options I have thought of are:

1). Send the object and then use that to build a query:

```
return this.$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: this.API_ADDRESS + 'vehicles/',
    data: vehicleSearchModel,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((response: any) => {
    return response.data;
  });
```

and retrieve it from the body using body-parser i.e.

```
request.body.data (or something similar)
```

or

2). send multiple params in the url i.e.

```
app.get('/api/vehicles/:make/:model/:bodyStyle/:fuelType/:transmission/:minPrice/:maxPrice/:minYear/:maxYear/:counties', function (request, response) {
    //Do something with request.params!!!
});
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should make the http post request as following.

```
var data = {
    make : make,
    model : model,
    fuelType : fueltype,
....
}
return this.$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: this.API_ADDRESS + 'vehicles/',
    data: vehicleSearchModel,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((response: any) => {
    return response.data;
  });
```

And then, you can receive the multiple parameters as following.

```
app.post('/api/vehicles/', function(req, res){
  var make = req.body.make;
  var model= req.body.model;
  var bodyStyle= req.body.bodyStyle;
  var fuelType= req.body.fuelType;
  var transmission= req.body.transmission;
.....
});
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is the route I will follow.